# How to make personal data fields non editable

Tags: extension, webform-civicrm, civisurvey

I received a survey titled 'civiCRM survey 2016' with my first name, last name and email fields pre-filled and not editable.
How did you achieve this? Are you using the no-overwrite extension or webforms disabled fields also work when using the civiCRM checksum?

Answer (score 2):

That survey uses a Webform-civicrm form. The 'existing contact' field has had 'Field Locking' applied to the Name and Email fields (first time i saw this feature - nice addition!).

if you want to achieve the same directly in civicrm profile when you add a field to the profile you have the option to set it to read-only.

ADDENDUM: Nathan below comments that "I believe this is available in Webform CiviCRM 7.x-4.15 based on the notes and code in the change comparison listed here: github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/compare/7.x-4.14...7.x-4.15"

Comment: Hi Pete, are you talking about the disabled checkbox (Make this field non-editable. Useful for setting an unchangeable default value) on the civi webform fields components?

Comment: nope. i am referring specifically to a 'field locking' option, which I have not seen before but was what was in use on that form on civi site (i have edit access hence dug in to the form to see how he had done it)

Comment: Can you tell me where this 'field locking' option is located? I don't seem to find it when the existing contact field is enabled and even when i click on edit i see other options and not the 'field locking'. I am using civi webform 7.4.14

Comment: Could this field locking be done by the drupal module https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_locked_fields  ?

Comment: RE. my last comment I tried this module, but it didn't work. Shame,

Comment: Just to add to this, and to answer @AndyClark above (if you haven't already found the answer). I believe this is available in Webform CiviCRM 7.x-4.15 based on the notes and code in the change comparison listed here: https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/compare/7.x-4.14...7.x-4.15 However, I have yet to try this.

Comment: Thanks Nathan - have edited my reply to include this infol

Comment: care to accept the answer and make StackExchange happy?